# Trunk mode not working in cisco switch

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I am setting up one 2960 cisco switches, i configured gi1/0/1 to be a trunk port but command not working:

```
switchport mode trunk

switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-10
```

i see this config in `show run`:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1

switchport trunk allowed vlan 1-10

switchport mode trunk
```

but interface working in `vlan 1` & i see this status in `show interface g1/0/1 trunk`:

```
Port        Mode             Encapsulation  Status        Native vlan
Gi1/0/1     on               802.1q         other         1

Port        Vlans allowed on trunk

Gi1/0/1     none

Port        Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi1/0/1     none

Port        Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi1/0/1     none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the cable, if your cable is damaged, your trunk port configuration will remain in vlan 1 and will not work.